# How to get scrollbar height in scrollviewer in uwp?

Tags: c#, uwp, scrollbar, uwp-xaml, scrollviewer

how to get scollbar height in scrollviewer in uwp just like shown in this photo.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> How to get scrollbar height in scrollviewer in uwp?

Please check [`ScrollBar`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.controls.primitives.scrollbar?view=winrt-19041) style(**stored in the general.xaml file**),  the matched part like above screenshot is `VerticalThumb`, you could copy the following style in your page resource, and detect `VerticalThumb` load event, and get the ActualHeight property with following code.

```
private void VerticalThumb_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    var verticalThumb = sender as Thumb;

    var height = verticalThumb.ActualHeight;
}
```

Comment: I think you use cortana uwp app in that app you will notice that the button that goes to newly add items automatically hide according to scroll bar. How can i program this feature in my Listview as i also have one button that visible when listview scroll up and hide when scroll down but when i resize my app window it won't work.........please help

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65787915/how-to-remove-flicker-or-blinking-when-removing-items-from-listview-in-uwp

Comment: Ok, I got it, please add your more code that could preproduce your problem